# Understanding aspect units in QGIS

Tags: spatial-analyst, qgis-2.14, units, aspect

I created an aspect raster form a DEM raster in QGIS 2.14, and got this results:

[image]

I know that the results refer to degree units , but still i don't understand how to read the map result- i mean to which direction the aspect turn.

In ESRI site http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-aspect-works.htm  , the spatial analyst doucumentation explain the aspect with this schem:

[image]

i seeked the same explanation in https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/terrain_analysis.html?highlight=aspect but didn't found anything like it.

How can i read and understand the aspect results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on which of the available aspect calculators you used as QGIS is beter thought of as a 'meta-GIS' rather than a single GIS as it provides a GUI for multiple GIS technologies (e.g. GDAL, GRASS, SAGA to name a few).  If you use the GDAL Aspect calculation from `Raster->Terrain Analysis->Aspect` then the values are the same as ESRI (degrees from North).  See [here](https://kingsgeocomputation.org/2016/03/16/aspect-slope-maps-in-qgis/) for more discussion.  I believe that SAGA's slope calculator also follows the convention of 0 clockwise from north (confirmed by a quick test) though I can't point you at any documentation.

If however, you used the GRASS [r.slope.aspect](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.slope.aspect.html), then it computes the values as degrees counterclockwise from East.